# how to listen for incoming jdbc connections?

Tags: python, jdbc, proxy

let's say that me and a partner are working on a python application that needs to connect to a database, exemple mysql:

```
import mysql.connector  
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="databaseURL",user="user",passwd="userPassword")
```

l am trying to **hide** my credentials from the code, but referencing them in anyway (from a file, environment variable, substitution ...etc.) doesn't work since he can simply print the value, or get them from memory, and clearing memory isn't an option in my use case.

one idea that l thought about is using a proxy, that sits between the python app and the database, this way l could connect to the db with some proxy credentials instead. exemple:

```
import mysql.connector  
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="proxyURL",user="proxyUser",passwd="proxyPassword")
```

basically if the credentials are valid, the proxy gonna request the actual credentials, and use them to connect to the database.

The difficulty that l found is how to to make a server listen for incoming JDBC connections? i.e. how to create a jdbc proxy. Otherwise is the approach even correct?

Comment: Forget it. Writng a MySQL proxy is a Herculean task.

Comment: is there any other way that l can reference those credentials, without my *partner being able to get them?

Comment: If they are personal credentials, get them from the user via a prompt. If they are application credentials, there's no reason to hide them from another developer of the same application.

Comment: that could do it, but the problem is the credentials end up in memory and l could easily get them from there

Comment: You can't solve that problem. All credentials end up in memory somewhere, in any application.

Comment: If you are using Python (and I assume MySQL Connector/Python), why have you tagged this JDBC and are you talking about JDBC?

Comment: MySQL was an example, while l need to support multiple databases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thinking about it, l don't think that's even possible, since each database has it own JDBC driver that communicates in its unique way with the database. this means that l need to write different proxies for each database.